# CakePHP 3.0.1 mensagem de erro

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp

Estou com um problema ao instalar o **CakePHP**, estou utilizando o **Xampp**, com o PHP 5.5, e apresenta a mensagem:

> Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in
>   C:\Users\inhome\Desktop\io\CAKEPHPROJECT\htdocs\projetoCake\config\bootstrap.php
>   on line 38

Já fiz uma pesquisa em fóruns, já mudei o `extension=php_intl.dll`, copiei os arquivos do `/xamp/php/ic*.dll` para `/xampp/apache/bin` conforme esse link do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system) e mesmo assim o problema persiste.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Verifique no arquivo php.ini se a linha parecida com isso, está com o caminho correto (no meu caso é onde as dlls estão ).
  extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext" //
Configure também a variável de ambiente PATH com o conteúdo
C:\xampp\php;(se ainda não estiver configurada)

Comment: Valeu @MarcosXavier, estava no trampo então editar as variaveis não era possivel, mas em casa resolveu tudo.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somente tirar o `;` antes de `extension=php_intl.dll`, ele ficará assim:

```
;extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
```

Após isso reiniciar o seu servidor e pronto, acessará normalmente.